# How to solve simultaneous equations faster with Compile?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, numerics

I have large 6x6 matrix `U`which is a multiplication of 15 rotational matrix. All of the elements are `Sin\[theta]` and `Cos\[Theta]`. I have to solve simultaneous equations using the matrix elements. Yesterday i ran the code for 14 hours with core i3 machine at windows 7. Still no output. I know that `Complie` can run code quicker but i am not an expert on this. So i need help. here is the code.I tried but failed to use complie here. how to use complie or how can i run the code faster?

```
Solve[U[[2,4]]==0.12 && U[[1,4]]==0.11 && U[[2,5]]==0.17 && U[[1,5]]==0.11 &&
      U[[2,6]]==0.14 && U[[1,6]]==0.11 &&
      U[[3,1]]==0    && U[[3,2]]==0    && U[[3,3]]==0    && U[[3,4]]==0    && 
      U[[3,5]]==0    && U[[3,6]]==0,
  {\[Theta]12, \[Theta]13, \[Theta]14, \[Theta]15, \[Theta]16, \[Theta]23, \[Theta]24, 
   \[Theta]25, \[Theta]26, \[Theta]34, \[Theta]35, \[Theta]36, \[Theta]45, \[Theta]46, 
   \[Theta]56}
]
```

Comment: Generally,you should try to provide self-contained examples so that the code can be run, to maximize our chances to provide reasonable answers. Here it means providing your matrix `U`.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't expect `Compile` to help you here. `Solve` is not compilable and it very unlikely that you could write your own linear solver that does a better job than `Solve`. If you have a 16x16 linear system and decimal approximations are sufficient, then `Solve` should be able to solve it nearly instantaneously. The information you have as written is really not quite sufficient to advise further, though.

Answer (score 6):

**There exists no solution.** A product of rotation matrices is invertible, but the last 6 constraints introduce an entire row of zeros in `U`, making its rank of 5 or less, whence it must *not* be invertible.

Here, then, is optimal code: :-)

```
Solve[False, {}]
```

*(0 seconds).*

---

Well, maybe that wasn't so constructive.  Let's see how we can find a product of rotation matrices in $n$ dimensions with specified components.  This method minimizes the $L^2$ norm of the differences at the desired locations.

Begin by specifying the places and the values to attain at those places:

```
places = {{2, 4}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {1, 6}, 
           {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}};
targets = {.12, .11, .17, .11, .14, .11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

The objective function is the sum of squares of differences at those places:

```
objective[u_] := With[{x = u~Extract~places - targets}, x.x];
```

*(This clear formulation is thanks to Mr.Wizard.)*

Rotation matrices in higher dimensions, for rotations from one basis vector to another, look like the usual rotation matrices in two dimensions, with ones elsewhere on the diagonal:

```
rotationMatrix[t_, n_Integer, i_Integer, j_Integer] /; 1 <= i <= n && 1 <= j <= n && i != j := 
 Module[{u = IdentityMatrix[n], s = Sin[t], c = Cos[t]},
  u[[{i, j}, {i, j}]] = {{c, -s}, {s, c}}; u
]
```

The variables to parameterize a generic rotation correspond to these "basis vector" rotations, which when multiplied give an arbitrary rotation.  The variables, `vars`, can be created at the same time the matrix product `u` is generated, cached via `Sow`, and collected via `Reap`:

```
With[{n = 6},
  vars = Flatten[Last[Reap[
      u = Dot @@ (Flatten[
          Table[rotationMatrix[Sow[Unique["\[Theta]"]], n, i, j], 
                {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}], 1])
  ]]]
];
```

Let's give it a whirl:

```
solution = NMinimize[objective[u], vars]
```

*(0.69 seconds).*

In this case, the best we can do is reduce the objective function to $1.$, not $0.$ (which would indicate a good solution).  We might characterize what we have found as a least-squares fit to the targets.  For the record, here it is:

```
Chop[u /. Last[solution]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Rotation matrix]

Comment: I'd replace `Outer[0 &, Range[n], Range[n]]` with `ConstantArray[0, {n, n}]` or even `Table[0, {n}, {n}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks--I knew there was a simple way, but I just wanted to get the job done and this method worked fine. I'm sure others (and maybe you again) will have additional improvements to suggest. (*E.g.*, you might find a nicer way to express `objective`.) If you like, just edit the post to make them; if not, I'll wait a bit and then edit it all at once.

Comment: It seems as though `objective` can be written: `objective[u_] := With[{x = u ~Extract~ places - targets}, x.x]` or `objective = #.# &[u ~Extract~ places - targets] &`